# Sql Convert value to int if possible, if not possible set value to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need Sql query which Convert value to int if possible, if not possible set value to 0.

```
SELECT IIF((isnumeric('11961630')),TRY_PARSE('11961630' as int), 0) => it should return 11961630
    SELECT IIF((isnumeric('CH11961630')),TRY_PARSE('CH11961630' as int), 0) => it should return 0
```

Comment: You really don't need to use `ISNUMERIC()`. As you have already one function `TRY_PARSE()` which will do conversation for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```sql
select isnull(try_parse('42' as int), 0) -- returns 42
select isnull(try_parse('fred' as int), 0) -- returns 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In case any reader would want a way to do this without using `TRY_PARSE` or any other of the more recent fancy conversion functions, it is possible to do this using only `LIKE` and `CAST`:

```
SELECT
    input,
    CASE WHEN input NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND
                    CAST(input AS DECIMAL(10,0)) BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647
         THEN CAST(input AS INT) ELSE 0 END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```